# Using wrong physics formulas

Tags: physics

[image]

We were given a couple formulas, but the one that immediately stood out to me was the Vfinal = Vinitial + at

so we know the patrol will constantly accelerate "until he pulls next to the speeding car" so Vfinal = 30m/s and Vinitial = 0(cop at rest) and the acceleration is a constant 3m/s^2

so 30 = 3t, t = 10. However when I continue through this lecture, it turns out t = 20. he uses the formula x = xo + v0t + 1/2at^2 and somehow gets a different time than me. I don't understand how it's possible that we are both solving for time but getting different results.

Is it safe to assume that when xo = 0 and v0 = 0 that

sqrt(2x/a) = Vfinal / a

since we cancel out terms and they both equal t?

Comment: One solution is given by $t=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake was that you tried finding the time it takes for the cop to achieve the same velocity ($30 \frac{m}{s}$). That’s not right for obvious reasons. The speeding car was already traveling at $30 \frac{m}{s}$ by the time the police car was stationary. Instead, you have to find the time it takes for the distance covered to become equal.

Car $1$: $\overline v = 30 \frac{m}{s} \implies \Delta x_1 = \overline v \cdot \Delta t$
Car $2$: $v_1 = 0 \frac{m}{s}; \overline a = 3 \frac{m}{s^2} \implies \Delta x_2 = \frac{1}{2}\overline a\Delta t^2+v_1\Delta t$

Keep in mind $\Delta x$ represents displacement, $\Delta t$ represents time, $v_1$ represents initial velocity, $\overline v$ represents average/uniform velocity, and $\overline a$ represents average/uniform acceleration.

We need to find the $\Delta t$ for which $\Delta x_1 = \Delta x_2$.

$$\Delta x_1 = \Delta x_2$$
$$\overline v\cdot\Delta t= \frac{1}{2}\overline a\Delta t^2+v_1\Delta t$$
$$30\Delta t = \frac{1}{2}3\Delta t^2+0(\Delta t)$$
$$30\Delta t = \frac{1}{2}3\Delta t^2$$
$$30 = 1.5\Delta t$$
$$\boxed{\Delta t = \frac{30}{1.5} = 20s}$$

Answer (score 1):

If the patrol car goes after the other starting from rest, then of course that, when it catches it, it must be going *faster* than the other car. Therefore, the final speed cannot possibly be $30$ *m*/*s*.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere does it say that the final speed of the cop is 30 m/s

If it was the cop will never reach the person, in order to reach them , they have to travel faster.

We don't know the final speed of the cop.

So the time is 20 seconds.